# cookie not getting deleted using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, session-cookies

I have searched various articles and links for deleting cookie using javascipt, but it seems the javascript not working. I used the below code for setting cookie value using javascript -

```
var now = new Date();
var time = now.getTime();
time += 3600 * 1000;
now.setTime(time);

document.cookie="name=" + $scope.user.name;
document.cookie="email=" + $scope.user.email;
document.cookie ="expires=" + now.toGMTString();
```

and then while trying to remove the cookie used the below code as in the link [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)-

```
document.cookie = "name= ;email= ;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
```

but nothing seems to work. the cookie is still present. I tried setting the cookie this way also -

```
document.cookie="name=" + $scope.user.name+";email=" + $scope.user.email+";expires=" + now.toGMTString();
```

and then again used the same delete operation but cookie iis not getting deleted. What is the problem. I can see that both ways of assigning cookie value is different but the cookie shouls be deleted which is not happening. I checked the results on chromium

> Version 50.0.2661.102 Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

and on opera

> Version:  37.0.2178.32

in both cases cookie is not getting deleted. One more information is I am including these two codes in two different API calls.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some problem which I am not able to figure it out. But, if add 'path=/' , then the cookie seems to be created and get deleted without any issue. the code for the same is as below for creation and deletion.

```
document.cookie="name="+$scope.user.name+";expires="+now.toGMTString()+";path=/";

document.cookie = "name=; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you do a `document.cookie` assignment, you're creating a new, separate cookie. For example your `document.cookie="name=" + $scope.user.name;` only sets the `name` and does not actually set an `expires` because you didn't provide the paramter, and your `document.cookie ="expires=" + now.toGMTString();` is actually creating a cookie with the name `expires`, not setting an expiry time.

When you do `document.cookie = "name= ;email= ;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";` however, that should cause the `name` cookie to expire, but leaving the `email` cookie there because the `email=` parameter is not a valid parameter for setting a cookie.

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie for proper usage. But in summary the valid parameters for setting a cookie is as follows:

> `;path=path` (e.g., '/', '/mydir') If not specified, defaults to the current path of the current document location.
>
> `;domain=domain` (e.g., 'example.com' or 'subdomain.example.com'). If not specified, defaults to the host portion of the current document location (but not including subdomains).
>
> `;max-age=max-age-in-seconds` (e.g., 60*60*24*365 or 31536e3 for a year)
>
> `;expires=date-in-GMTString-format` If not specified it will expire at the end of session.
>
> `;secure` (cookie to only be transmitted over secure protocol as https)

Comment: you are correct. I am using the way you have mentioned, but the problem here is cookie is not getting deleted after using `document.cookie = "name=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";`  I am using `document.cookie="name="+$scope.user.name+";expires="+now.toGMTString();` for setting the cookie.